# Question migrated to a stack exchange site with no tag for the primary technology

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

I'm wondering if it's really reasonable for a question to be migrated to a stack exchange site that doesn't even have a tag for the main technology in question. It's not really fair to send someone off to a site where nobody using the technology actually looks...

One of the values of Stack Overflow is that there are a substantial number of folks who will look at the question. I just had a question migrated and the destination site has a grand total of 22 questions that mention the technology, and zero tags related to that technology. How is this supposed to help? Perhaps such migrations even if theoretically appropriate should wait until a matching tag is available, and there is a community in place that can service the question?

I'd be fine if I'd been migrated to a place where the technology was actually discussed, but in effect I've been sent off to start a colony in siberia... Not what I thought I was volunteering for :)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question? Where was it migrated? What tags does it need?

Comment: [The question in question.](http://serverfault.com/questions/360851/how-can-i-ensure-liferay-uses-tls-for-authentication)

Comment: Well, I didn't want to get into whining about my specific case... if you really want the specific case I can of course add the link.

Comment: Specifics are good. :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/360851/how-can-i-ensure-liferay-uses-tls-for-authentication - The question is not really an ldap question (and the answer may be that it can't based on my ongoing research), It's a how do I make Liferay do the right thing question. Nobody on Server Fault seems to be interested in Liferay to begin with. (with a few exceptions)